# Summing # of occurrences of column values conditional to values in another column

Tags: r

I have a large data frame (`g1`) consisting of columns `count`, `cdr3`, and `length`, with `cdr3` and `length` being pertinent to my problem.

The column `cdr3` consists of a number of strings, with column length giving the length of the string. There are, as such, 70 unique values for length.

What's a quick and clean way to aggregate the number of strings (column `cdr3` values) that are of a particular length?

Comment: What have you tried? How about making a reproducible example showing where you got stuck? Here are some tips on how to proceed with the example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: See `?table` and try `table(g1$length)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly..

Element in the `cdr` column is a string.
And `length` column is the length of that string?

Say if you want to know the occurrence of string of length x.

Something like this should work.

```
total = 0
i = 1
while (i < length(cdr3)+ 1) {
    i = i + 1
    if (nchar(cdr[i]) == x) {
        total = total + 1
    }
}
```